# Void vs Int output argument signature

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management

I can write a simple function to add 2 numbers using function two ways. One of them uses void output function signature and the other uses int output function signature. I notice that the first one is more commonly used by programmers.

Here is the first code

```
#include<iostream>
void add(int x, int y, int* z)
{
  z[0] = x + y;
}
int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = 10;
  int c = 0;
  add(a, b, &c);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the second code

```
#include<iostream>
int add(int x, int y)
{
  int z;
  z = x + y;
  return z;
}
int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = 10;
  int c;
  c = add(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

When i compiled the code using gcc and saw the symbols by using *objdump*. I noticed very minute difference between two. In fact, the second code has one instruction lesser, assuming *LEA* and *MOV* has same number of execution cycles. Are there some advantages using the first style of coding versus the second? Maybe, the vice-versa may be true.

I searched stackexchange for this question and I found this ([Void vs Int Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707604/void-vs-int-functions)), but this doesn't explain.

Comment: "I notice that the first one is more commonly used by programmers." it isn't. Not in c++ anyway.

Comment: Also `*z = x + y;` makes more sense than `z[0]` in this case.

Comment: Oh i see. So, in C++, the programmer would use the second style? Yes, I could possibly use *z = x + y;.

Comment: The second style allows you to do `result = add(a, b) * add(c, d)`. It's more useful as a building-block to allow composing larger expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you think the first one is more used, it's far more likely that the second one is since it allows you to chain expressions, like:

```
int xyzzy = add (42, 18) / add (15, 15);
```

That's not so elegant with the `void` variant:

```
int xyzzy;
add (42, 18, &xyzzy);
{
    int temp;
    add (15, 15, &temp);
    xyzzy /= temp;
}
```

In any case, real C++ programmers (as opposed to C programmers who *claim* to be C++ programmers) wouldn't use a pointer for pass-by-reference when C++ provides a perfectly good way of passing reference variables:

```
void add(int x, int y, int& z) // or even && for C++11.
```

Comment: So, does the first style of coding offers benefits when coded in C? I do see that all of the answers point to the second style in C++.

Comment: @Lokesh, the first one is currently the only way in C to emulate pass-by-reference. Hopefully ISO C21 will give us reference variables like in C++.

Answer (score 1):

the first style, mostly, (was) used for *heavy* objects (for which copy operation is expensive) and, possible, w/ compilers without (N)RVO which helps to elide deep object copying.

actually, as you've been told, C++ programmers prefer the second style, because it looks (and behave) naturally: function accept some input params and produce the only result as a return.

with C++11 and movable objects necessity for the first style become almost zero, so almost all functions can be written in a natural way.

Comment: Whats NRVO? With movable objects in C++11, I see that the second style  will be preferred.